How to write a custom in-place formatter from lambda?
I kind of don't like the existing API of the fmtlib (and its std variant) to customize formatters for different types:

I expected a more conventional approach of providing an in-place lambda.
Can only have a single template specialization for a type.
Specializations can't be declared anywhere but in its own namespace (can't specialize std::formatter inside foo namespace)
Impossible to specialize local or unnamed types.
fmtlib doesn't provide a way to format each element in a container (fmt::join can only set a delimiter). It would be very inconvenient to format fundamental and std types.

I would like to have something like the following:
int main() {
    struct {} john_cena;
    // std::cout << std::format("{}/n", john_cena, [](const auto&) { /**/ });
    // ^^^ How can I have that?
}


Interesting, but when would you need to go through std::format in such a case?

@TedLyngmo sorry, I didn't get your question. I am generating a meta data structure for reflection from nested struct with fields, and writing the string template in one place is more convenient that writing every subtemplate separately. Also, as I mentioned in the points, I'd have to have a "namespace gap" in order to provide specialiazations for custom types. Also, I see no simple way to "format each string in a container" using the api.

I think I'd need more context to understand how this helps. If you have struct {} john_cena; (possibly with some members) and want to print that, you would not need a std::formatter specialization for the unnamed struct. std::format("{} {}", john_cena.a, john_cena.b) would work, but I'm probably missing something.

@TedLyngmo I benefit the most of formatting each element. Let's say the struct has a member std::vector<std::string> titles and you want to print "name: {name}, {titles}" and for each title you have to print "title: {title}". std::vector<std::string> is very easy and sufficient for every other usage of this data, and there's no reason to have a wrapper type for std::string in this case but to satisfy the api requirements. With this solution you can have fmt::join("\n", {titles, "title: {}"}) (simplified form). And have the whole string template in one place

Simplest and naive solution using a wrapper template. Lambdas are guaranteed to have unique types, so there are infinite ways to format one type.
I didn't provide the parse interface here, since I think it would be rather redundant.
Haven't tried with arrays though yet.

#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Format, typename = void>
struct with_fmt{
    const T &value;
    Format format;
};

template <typename T, typename Format>
struct with_fmt<T, 
    Format, 
    std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()), 
        decltype(std::declval<T>().end())>> {
    const T &value;
    Format format;

    using _wrapped_value_type = decltype(*std::declval<const T&>().begin());
    using _wrapped_iterator_type = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().begin());
    using value_type = with_fmt<_wrapped_value_type, Format>;

    struct iterator_type {
        using value_type = with_fmt::value_type;

        _wrapped_iterator_type i;
        value_type operator*() const {
            return {.value = *i, .format = Format{}};
        }
        _wrapped_iterator_type operator++() { return ++i;}
        bool operator==(const iterator_type& other) const { return i == other.i; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator_type& other) const { return i != other.i; }
    };

    constexpr iterator_type begin() const { return {.i = value.begin()}; }
    constexpr iterator_type end() const { return {.i = value.end()}; }
};

template <typename T, typename Format>
with_fmt(const T&, Format) -> with_fmt<T, Format>;

template <typename T, typename Format, typename Char>
struct fmt::formatter<with_fmt<T, Format>, Char> {
    constexpr auto parse(fmt::format_parse_context &ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }
    constexpr auto format(const with_fmt<T, Format> &uf, fmt::format_context &ctx) const {
        return uf.format(uf.value, ctx);
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    struct {} john_cena;
    std::cout << fmt::format("And his name is... {}\n", 
        with_fmt{
            .value = john_cena, 
            .format = 
                [](const auto&, fmt::format_context &ctx)
                {
                    // todo: return `std::tuple{"{}", "John Cena"}`
                    return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", "John Cena");
                }});

    std::cout << fmt::format("{}\n", 
        with_fmt{
            .value = john_cena, 
            .format = 
                [](const auto&, fmt::format_context &ctx)
                {
                    return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", "You can't see me");
                }});

    std::cout << fmt::format(
        "Imagine how hard it would be to define a custom formatter for a simple `int`: \n{}",
        fmt::join(
            with_fmt{
                .value = std::vector{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42},
                .format = 
                [](int i, fmt::format_context &ctx) {
                    return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{i} Mississippi...", fmt::arg("i", i));
                }}, "\n"));

    return 0;


Updated with usage for containers: https://godbolt.org/z/sq1818vjo
I might update with a less contrived example and a cleaner interface.

I think, the simplest way to it is using a lambda to do a custom formatter, such as this below:
struct MyLocalStruct {};  // local struct type
MyLocalStruct mylocalstruct;

auto custom_format = [](const auto& obj) -> std::string {
    // replace this with the actual formatting logic for your local struct
    // you can call std::format to do whatever you want ...
    // for example, std::format("MyLocalStruct: name = {}", obj.name);
    return "here is my formatted MyLocalStruct";
};

std::cout << custom_format(mylocalstruct) << "\n";

Otherwise, you have to make your local types as global ones, then use std::formatter.

and how would you use it with fmt::join(MyLocalStructVector, "\n"), which does expect a fmt::formatter specialization? The question is about abusing fmtlib api in order to write a cleaner string template. Your solution is basically handcrafting strings

Do you want to handle local struct? If so, that's the way to it, otherwise you have to make your local struct type global.

look at my answer and you'll see not only a local struct formatting, but also a custom formatter for int, which already has a fmt::formatter<int, char> specialization

Ok. your solution introduced more usage difficulties. Btw, you can use std::views::transform() to convert myLocalStruct or a vector of it into a vector of formatted strings, eg,
auto formattedStrings = myLocalStructVector | std::views::transform(custom_format);
Then, use fmt::join to join the formatted strings.

using transforms is a viable alternative, but it would still require do a lot of logic by hand in order to have fmtlib's optimizations. I will consider and compare this alternative in the actual code. But otherwise, having fmt::join(container, delimiter, formatter) would be a much cleaner api instead of forcing template specializations. Using side tools in this regard is not far from writing loops with printing line by line
